# Payment service with 1-to-many relationship

Tags: paypal, payment, stripe-payments, braintree

We're building a service that acts as a marketplace, but in which there are several beneficiaries for a single payment (not distributed equally between each part).

Let's take an example:

- One of my customer wants to buy 100 bricks (1$/brick).
- Many sellers have some bricks to sell, seller A sells 30, seller B sells 60, and seller C sells 10
- I want to give back 30$ to seller A, 60$ to seller B and 10$ to seller C directly on their bank account

**Which payment service can I use?** I contacted both Stripe and Braintree but they're only capable to re-distribute the amount to a single person. PayPal would be a great option but we didn't found any way to push money directly on a bank account via API (or at least on a PayPal account).

Comment: I forgot to notice that I charge a fee based on a percentage before giving back to sellers. In my example, let's say the fee is 10%, they'll earn respectively 30%, 60% and 10% of 90$ (100$ after fees applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) will get the model done for you, but you can't pay directly to somebody's bank.  It would go to their PayPal, and then they can transfer to their bank account from there.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that perfectly fits my needs!